# How to resolve RabbitMq connection issues after upgrading Rebus from 0.71.4 to 0.75.2?

Tags: rebus

How to resolve RabbitMq connection issues after upgrading Rebus from 0.71.4 to 0.75.2?

We have a distributed processor setup with N dashboards for monitoring activity, one manager for controlling workflow, and N workers for performing the work. Communication between each component is managed using RabbitMq. Everything has been working great [on Rebus 0.71.4], until we upgraded to Rebus 0.75.2 (which included an upgrade of RabbitMq.Client to 3.4.0.0).

The manager is the most complicated component, as it sends multiple forms of communication including, a heartbeat published to workers, request/response audit messages published to dashboards, and messages including work to be performed by the workers.  All of this messaging is being done concurrently.

We are using a prefetch of 1 in order to prevent work getting held up by longer running tasks on workers (jobs range between 1 second and 5 minutes).

Now, we're getting an erratic exception during Publish within the manager.:

`2015-01-07 14:59:58.6205 | Error | An error occurred while rolling back the transaction! RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.AlreadyClosedException Already closed: The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=504, text="CHANNEL_ERROR - unexpected command while processing 'tx.commit'", classId=60, methodId=40, cause=    at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SessionBase.Transmit(Command cmd)
       at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.ModelBase.TransmitAndEnqueue(Command cmd, IRpcContinuation k)
       at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.ModelBase.ModelRpc(MethodBase method, ContentHeaderBase header, Byte[] body)
       at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.Model.TxRollback()
       at System.Action.Invoke()
       at Rebus.Bus.TxBomkarl.RaiseDoRollback()
       at Rebus.Bus.Worker.<TryProcessIncomingMessage>d__1d.MoveNext()`

`2015-01-07 14:59:58.6275 | Warn | User exception in Rebus 1 worker 1: Rebus.Bus.QueueCommitException: An exception occurred while attempting to commit the queue transaction ---> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.OperationInterruptedException: The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=504, text="CHANNEL_ERROR - unexpected command while processing 'tx.commit'", classId=60, methodId=40, cause=
       at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SimpleBlockingRpcContinuation.GetReply()
       at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.ModelBase.ModelRpc(MethodBase method, ContentHeaderBase header, Byte[] body)
       at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.Model.TxCommit()
       at System.Action.Invoke()
       at Rebus.Bus.TxBomkarl.RaiseDoCommit()
       at Rebus.Bus.Worker.<TryProcessIncomingMessage>d__1d.MoveNext()
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at Rebus.Bus.Worker.<TryProcessIncomingMessage>d__1d.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>b__0(Object state)
       at Rebus.Bus.RebusSynchronizationContext.Run()
       at Rebus.Bus.Worker.MainLoop()`

These are some related entries from the RabbitMq log:

`=ERROR REPORT==== 7-Jan-2015::15:41:54 ===
    Error on AMQP connection <0.680.0> ([::1]:59429 -> [::1]:5672, vhost: 'efs', user: 'efs.eod', state: running), channel 1:
    {amqp_error,channel_error,"unexpected command while processing 'tx.commit'",
                'basic.publish'}`

`=WARNING REPORT==== 7-Jan-2015::15:42:55 ===
    closing AMQP connection <0.553.0> ([::1]:59421 -> [::1]:5672):
    connection_closed_abruptly`

We have tested against RabitMq Server 3.3.5 and 3.4.3.

This behavior is reproducible, but sporadic. And, when it does function correctly, communication is much slower than it was on 0.71.4.

We have been unable to thus far reproduce the issue in isolation. Any advice for diagnosing the issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Weird! I've tried to reproduce it by exercising Rebus' RabbitMQ transport with various prefetch counts, but so far I've been unsuccessful.

Could you maybe describe to me some more details about your setup? Or, ideally, send me a minimal reproduction?

Comment: We're working on that minimal reproducable project. There is a significant amount of domain logic we must pulling out. In the mean time I'll see if I can come up with a more detailed description of what we're doing.